# Nullability of terminals

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata-theory

```
S -> AB
A -> aAA | ε
A -> bBB | ε
```

So in the above example things are fairly straight forward, you just find the nullable symbols, eliminate the ε, and construct a new production that could get the job done without the empty string and we get this..

```
S -> AB | A | B
S -> aAA | aA | aA | a
S -> bBB | bB | bB | b
```

And then I came across this example

```
S -> ABaC
A -> B
B -> b | ε
C -> c | ε
```

Now A produces B, and B can clearly produce an empty string. Does than mean A is nullable is S and is it possible to, I don't know, nullify a terminal if it doesn't produce a nullable terminal directly?

Comment: A nullable symbol is one which can produce an empty string.  I'm not sure what you mean by "nullify" or how you would "nullify a terminal".  It is also impossible to have a "nullable terminal", since terminals are *never* nullable.  Only non-terminals can be nullable.  I recommend reviewing the definitions.

Comment: I meant nonterminals. I apologize for the confusion, but your answer clears it up so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, A is nullable because B can clearly produce *ε*. However, S is not nullable because there is always the terminal *a* in its production rule.